# M-P: M-p is undefined

Tags: keystrokes

I noticed something odd.  If I press `M-P` I get the message `M-p is
undefined` rather than `M-P etc.`.  Is there a reason for this?

Version 26.2.  Using Arch Linux and the X window system.

Comment: Try using `describe-key` on both keys. It might be translated.

Comment: @DoMiNeLa10, that works as expected.  just curious about this behaviour.

Comment: Does it mention that keys are translated in some way? If they are, that's your answer - someone set them up to be translated, and you might even get a link to see where it's been done.

Comment: @DoMiNeLa10, no, this happens with `-q`.

Comment: I can't reproduce that from `emacs -Q`. Is this in a terminal? OS may also affect key input.

Comment: @npostavs, odd. not in the terminal.

Comment: Uh, unless this is just confusion over notation, by "press `M-P`" did you mean press `Alt+Shift+p` or `Alt+p`?

Comment: @npostavs, alt-shift-p

Comment: Hmm, dunno then. If you `(progn (define-key global-map (kbd "M-P") 'foo) (define-key global-map (kbd "M-p") 'bar))` do you get different results?

Comment: @npostavs, yes, and describe-key shows M-p as expected

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a feature.  Refer to this duplicate Q&A on the main S.O. site:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/54591047/324105

It's still slightly misleading, given that in your case the lower-case sequence *also* has no binding (as the docs *imply* that the translation only occurs when there is a lower-case binding), but I think it's all part and parcel of the same mechanism.

`read_key_sequence` contains the following comments:

```
  /* If KEY is not defined in any of the keymaps,
 and cannot be part of a function key or translation,
 and is an upper case letter
 use the corresponding lower-case letter instead.  */
 [...]
  /* We have to do this unconditionally, regardless of whether
     the lower-case char is defined in the keymaps, because they
     might get translated through function-key-map.  */
  [...]
  shift_translated = true;
```